# AssertionError: The field ' ' was declared on serializer ' ', but has not been included in the 'fields' option

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using 'Django Rest Framework' and I am trying to build a RestfulAPI. However I get the above error when I run my app : `AssertionError: The field 'doctor' was declared on serializer AnimalSerialiser, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.` I am not sure what `fields` are and therefore can't track down the issue.

My models.py :

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Doctor(models.Model):

    id= models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id

class Animal(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    breed = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    adoption = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    vaccines = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, null=True)
```

My serialisers.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Animal, Doctor

class DoctorSerealiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
         model = Doctor
         fields = ('id' , 'name')


class AnimalSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    doctor = DoctorSerealiser()


    class Meta:
        model = Animal
        fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'gender' , 'breed' , 'adoption' , 'vaccines', 'Doctor')
```

My views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets, generics

from cw.myStart.models import Animal
from cw.myStart.serializers import AnimalSerialiser, DoctorSerealiser
from models import Animal, Doctor

class AnimalList(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Animal.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AnimalSerialiser

class DoctorDetail(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Doctor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DoctorSerealiser
```

Comment: Maybe it is because you use `Doctor` instead of `doctor` in `fields`?

Comment: on a side note, you are using `serializer`, `serialiser` and `serealiser`. I beg you to use `serializer` (the spelling "imposed" by DRF) to avoid chaos.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to modify your `doctor` field name to be the proper case:

```
fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'gender' , 'breed' , 'adoption' , 'vaccines', 'doctor')
```

`Doctor` is currently, incorrectly uppercase.

Answer (score 18):

The answers above already fix this specific issue. For me, I saw this error for entirely different reason, I was missing a comma in `fields` list after one of the attribute `id`, so I got the error regarding `name`.

```
class SomeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = (
                  'id' # missed a comma here
                  'name'
                 )
```

Answer (score 8):

Whatever field you will define in Serializer, you need to put it in the meta class fields. If you don't mention you will get the error.

> builtins.AssertionError
>   AssertionError: The field 'abc' was declared on serializer ABCSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.

So in your case you have defined **doctor** field in serializer so you meta fields should have this doctor field. It is **case-sensitive**. So you will have to use **doctor** instead of **Doctor**.

```
class AnimalSerialiser(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
doctor = DoctorSerealiser()


class Meta:
    model = Animal
    fields = ('id' , 'name' , 'gender' , 'breed' , 'adoption' , 'vaccines', 'doctor')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  class RepairListCreateView(APIView):
  """
  List all repairs, or create a new repair.
  """
  serializer_class = RepairSerializer
  permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]

  def get(self, request, format=None):
    """
    Return a list of all repairs.
    """
    repairs = Repair.objects.all()
    serializer = self.serializer_class(repairs, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

  def post(self, request, format=None):
    """
    Create a new repair.
    """
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
    print(request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
      serializer.save()
      return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    class Repair(models.Model):
  """
  Model for a repair
  """

  STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('P', 'Pending'),
    ('C', 'Completed'),
    ('A', 'Approved'),
    ('R', 'Rejected'),
  )

  user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  description = models.TextField()
  status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='P')
  is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
  
  class Meta:
    """
    Meta definition for Repair
    """
    db_table = 'Repairs'
    verbose_name = 'Repair'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Repairs'

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

The field 'user_id' was declared on serializer RepairSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option